# Unable to run Java code on MATLAB Runtime in Unix environment

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

After exporting a matlab function to java package. I have tried to run the following code unix environment which contains MATLAB runtime.

```
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWArray;
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWCharArray;
import calibrationAPINew.Calibration;

public class CHIndexCalculation {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

              MWCharArray number1 = null;
              Object[] result = null;
              Calibration calibration = null;
              String data = "{\r\n" +
                        "\"tsId\" : \"121213\",\r\n" +
                        "\"datapoints\" : [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4]\r\n" +
                        "}";

              try
              {
                 System.out.println("Input data: " + data);
                 number1 = new MWCharArray(data); // Array of Input to be sent to MATLAB Runtime
                 System.out.println("MWCharArray: " + number1);
                 calibration = new Calibration();
                 result = calibration.calibrationAPI(1,number1);

                 System.out.println("Output : " +  result[0]);
              }
              catch (Exception e)
              {
                System.out.println("Exception Occurred : " + e);
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
              finally
              {
                 //MWArray.disposeArray(number1);
                 //MWArray.disposeArray(result);
                 //calibration.dispose();
              }

        }
}
```

I have installed the matlabruntime on unix box and set the environment variables using export statement

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=matlabrt/v92/runtime/glnxa64:matlabrt/v92/bin/glnxa64:matlabrt/v92/sys/os/glnxa64:matlabrt/v92/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64
```

Now when I try to run the command ( `calibrationAPINew.jar` is the jar file exported from MATLAB)

```
java -cp javabuilder.jar:calibrationAPINew.jar:. CHIndexCalculation
```

I get the following exception

```
com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException: Undefined function 'pdist2mex' for input arguments of type 'double'.
        at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.mclFeval(Native Method)
        at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.access$600(MWMCR.java:31)
        at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR$6.mclFeval(MWMCR.java:882)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR$5.invoke(MWMCR.java:769)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.mclFeval(Unknown Source)
        at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.invoke(MWMCR.java:443)
        at calibrationAPINew.Calibration.calibrationAPI(Calibration.java:223)
        at CHIndexCalculation.main(CHIndexCalculation.java:24)
```

I know this has something to do with MATLAB runtime but I am unable to figure out what ? The same set up works fine on windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the matlab program uses some mexfile which is already compiled for windows, so that it is working perfect on windows. Since the mexfile is already available it will work perfect on windows. But when your script failed to find the corresponding mexfile for linux it fails or tries to compile the source files for linux using the function 'pdist2mex' which is not included in the jar package.In windows there is no need of this function so it works fine. If this is the case then you can either add the function 'pdist2mex' to your jar from matlab or you should compile the sources to linux compatible mex-file manually using matlab and then try to repackage it then the matlab automatically wrap the corresponding mex file to the jar

Comment: I will give it  a try